# how to write oracle two instance information in single query?

Tags: oracle

i using oracle 10g database, i installed two instance in my machine(dev and dev10g), i using query "select instance_name,status from v$instance"  this query return one instance information but i need two (dev and dev10g) instance information, how i write a query. it is possible without using dblink. pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

No. Without a dblink, the two database instances do not communicate with each other. Also, not sure if you can dblink v$instance.

If you want to monitor several databases in one place, you will need to look at Oracle's management tools, I think. Or just query both databases separately.

Comment: thank Thilo. i understand. any Oracle's management tools pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can see multiple instances if you use RAC but I don't think you are in this case.  As mentioned above, each instance is separate - even with the same software.  If you just want to know if the instance is alive, you can easily do this from the OS.

For example in linux:

```
ps -elf |grep pmon
```

This will check that the pmon process is running on the instance.  If its not you're in trouble!  The SID will be a part of the name - so if there are two instances running, you will see both.

In Windoz, you can check the services in a similar way.

Have you looked at Oracles Enterprice Manager Console?

Comment: thanks pj for ur suggestion. i will try windows services related